# Strange performance problem

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am recompiling a old Delphi program (from Delphi 2007) in (Delphi 2010). The code is absolutely unchanged and it compiles well. The key part of the program is the use of CopyFileExW to copy some files. Everything works OK and Dandy, however, there are some strange performance problems that I cannot understand where they come from.

When copying from a client computer to a Windows server the following happens:

- Version compiled with D2007
- From XP to Windows Server 2003, Copy performance OK
- From XP to Windows Server 2008 Copy performance OK
- From Windows 7 to Windows Server 2003, Copy performance OK
- From Windows 7 to Windows server 2008 Copy performance OK
- Version compiled with Delphi 2010
- From XP to Windows Server 2003, Copy performance OK
- From XP to Windows Server 2008 Copy performance OK
- From Windows 7 to Windows Server 2003, Copy performance OK
- From Windows 7 to Windows server 2008 Copy performance EXTREMLY SLOW

I can understand that perhaps there is an issue between the 2008 server and W7, like Remote Differential Compression or such (which BTW is disabled), but why does the version compiled with 2007 doesn't have the same problem? Any guesses?

Comment: Have you tried profiling it? Any decent profiler should be able to pinpoint the problem to a specific procedure for the problematic setup. Without profiling, there's no sure way to know it really is related to CopyFileExW.

Comment: Perhaps it is anti-virus software considering the D2010-compiled version suspicious and monitors all disk writes? Try temporarily disabling your anti-virus software.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code on how you copy the files? (Yes, you specify `CopyFileExW`, but you do not indicate how you call that, for instance with the kind of parameters or string conversions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas of possible causes:

- AntiVirus software on WS2008 side thinking that the transfer is suspicious and making verifications (as already stated in the comments).
- Possibly some implicit string conversion getting in the way.

Comment: That was it. Symantec AV. Excluding the destination worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are just now updating a program to run on Delphi 2010, you should probably go to Delphi XE and start solving problems there.  It comes with a profiler built in AND you get to work with the newest stuff.

Comment: Note that the built-in profiler in XE is a "light" version, and AFAIK, does NOT profile down to the specific source code line number.